# Logger is not defined, Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I'm sure I'm doing something incredibly stupid here, but I have a very simple function which is supposed to be called when button is clicked in my HTML form created through google apps script. Function is just as follows:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
Logger.log("Clicked");
})
```

But when I click it, nothing is logged and my console shows the error "userCodeAppPanel:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: Logger is not defined"... can't work out where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail of your script, how about modifying ``Logger.log("Clicked");`` to ``console.log("Clicked");``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should log via [Console Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_console.asp) `console.log("My log");`

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer specifically because the jQuery you're executing is not Google Apps Script code, while `Logger.log()` is only available in Google Apps Script files (i.e. files with the `.gs` extension).

Comment: oh yes sorry I kind of accepted the wrong one - although I think both are correct. Shame I can't accept both!

Answer (score 1):

`Logger` is available only in google apps script `.gs` file environment and not in javascript environment.

So if you want to log in javascript then you can use `console.log(message)`

If you're adamant or want to log into google apps script logs then you can create a function like this and make logs by passing message to that

```
// In .gs file
function make_log(message) {
    Logger.log(message)
}

// In frontend/html/js code
$("#click").click(function(){
    google.script.run.make_log("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: thank you all! Yes indeed I was being very stupid on this ! Cheers for the help

Comment: I would add a comment or two about the difference between `Logger` and `console` in the Apps Script/.gs environment, and `console` in the browser/.html environment